# Should I be using [autorelease]?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, retain, autorelease

I'm needing to quickly and simply parse an XML file in my app. The best solution for me seems to be something along the lines of an XML-to-NSDictionary converter which I can then dig through easier.

I chose to use this small class: http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/09/simple-xml-to-nsdictionary-converter/

However I'm confused about the returned `NSDictionary*` and its state in memory. The class method `dictionaryForXMLData` allocs and inits the class. `objectWithData` then goes off and does the heavy lifting returning the `NSDictionary` object which gets returned to the caller.

The confusing part for me is `[reader release]` before the return (I understand this must happen because of the way `reader` was created). My understanding of `NSDictionary`is that all the objects will also be sent the `release` message which means the object that we're returning shouldn't have a retain count. Note that the object is created with a convenience method and only gets a retain count when it is added to the stack.

Should the return statement not be `return [rootDictionary autorelease]`. The problem I see with that is that there is no telling when `rootDictionary` will be released and depending on the size of the XML file it could sit there clogging memory? Or do I have it all wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they are doing is not correct. The object returned by `objectWithData:` is possibly simply a reference to something retained inside `reader`. And by releasing `reader`, you are potentially deallocating the `rootDictionary` you got earlier. Depending on the inner workings of the `XMLReader` class, it is possible that the thing they return from `objectWithData:` is retained and autoreleased; but that is an implementation detail, and you cannot depend on it (plus Cocoa memory management is local, so you should never care about what other functions do).

The correct thing to do would be to retain the `rootDictionary` you get, and then autorelease it (to balance the retain since you have to return it without ownership).

```
+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryForXMLData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError **)error
{
    XMLReader *reader = [[XMLReader alloc] initWithError:error];
    NSDictionary *rootDictionary = [[[reader objectWithData:data] retain] autorelease];
    [reader release];
    return rootDictionary;
}
```

Comment: Ok, so my understanding was correct. Yes my mistake on the `return [rootDictionary autorelease]` should be after a `retain` and before the `release` as you have.

Comment: I've addressed my concern about a possibly large `NSDictionary` remaining in memory until the autorelease pool releases it by using an `@autorelease` block to scope the XML to `NSDictionary` conversion. That should prevent anything hanging around and clogging memory longer than necessary.

Comment: @Calvin: Sure, you can add an autorelease block. But then you should make sure anything you want to "bring out" of the autorelease block (the `rootDictionary` in this case) is retained. So you should leave the `retain` on that line, but move the `autorelease` to the last line where you return, outside of the autorelease block